# How to check if a file exists in a makefile

Tags: file, makefile, compilation, testing, gnu-make

I have a makefile template to compile a single DLL (for a plugin system).
The makefile of the user looks like this:

```
EXTRA_SRCS=file1 file2
include makefile.in
```

In the `makefile.in` I have:

```
plugin.dll: plugin.os $(patsubst %,%.os,$(EXTRA_SRCS))
```

Where `plugin.os` is the main C++ file to be compiled. Btw, the files ending is `.os` are the object files compiled for shared library (i.e. using the `-fpic` option with `gcc`)

Now, the problem is that the extra sources will probably (but not necessarily) be header files. Ideally I would like to add them as dependencies for the target `plugin.os` and the `file.cpp`, but only if they exist.

The method should work for both windows and linux, or at least be adaptable to each. However, I only use the GNU version of make.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the "wildcard" function:

```
$(wildcard *.h)
```

EDIT: in order to match a specific list, do

```
$(wildcard $(HEADER_FILES))
```

There is no need to use $(filter ...), the wildcard function automatically filters files which don't exist.

Comment: That's ok, you don't need to use wildcards. Use $(wildcard $(HEADER_FILES))

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify what compiler(s) you are using, but if you have access to gcc/g++ you can use the -MM option.

What I do is create a file with the extension of .d for every .c or .cpp file, and then "include" the .d files.  I use something like this in my Makefile:

```
%.d: %.c
        gcc $(INCS) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< -MF $@

%.d: %.cpp
        g++ $(INCS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $< -MF $@
```

I then create the dependencies like this:

```
C_DEPS=$(C_SRCS:.c=.d)
CPP_DEPS=$(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.d)
DEPS=$(C_DEPS) $(CPP_DEPS)
```

and this at the bottom of the Makefile:

```
include $(DEPS)
```

Is this the kind of behavior you're going for?  The beauty of this method is that even if you're using a non-GNU compiler for actual compiling, the GNU compilers do a good job of calculating the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Does the simple

```
$(filter $(wildcard *.h),$(HEADER_FILES))
```

do what you want?

Comment: mmhh .. I didn't know about this filter command ! what do it do ?

Comment: Read Make's documentation (info pages, not manpage): $(filter PATTERNS,TEXT) is the words in TEXT which match at least one of PATTERNS.  (PATTERN being make filepatterns, not regexes, so a plain filename must match exactly.)