# How to check whether a file exists, outside a Makefile rule?

Tags: file, if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

This is a pseudo code:

```
if .gitignore exists 
    GITIGNORE_PATH := .gitignore
else
    GITIGNORE_PATH := ../.gitignore
fi

all: 
    do_build...
```

I tried to search this, but they always show how to do this inside rules, as in:

```
$(UBIN)/%:
    @if [ -f '$@' ]; then \
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o '$@' $(OBJS) -L $(ORAHOME) $(ORALIBS) \
        $(LNKPATH) $(DSTN_LIBS); \
        echo ""; \
    fi
```

1. [Testing if a file exists in a make file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845614/testing-if-a-file-exists-in-a-make-file)
2. [Testing if a file exists in makefile target, and quitting if not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348741/testing-if-a-file-exists-in-makefile-target-and-quitting-if-not-present)
3. [How to check if a file exists in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250082/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
GITIGNORE_PATH := $(if $(wildcard .gitignore),,../).gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
# Read it as `if .gitignore file exists`
ifneq (,$(wildcard .gitignore))
    GITIGNORE_PATH := .gitignore
else
    GITIGNORE_PATH := ../.gitignore
endif

all:
    echo GITIGNORE_PATH ${GITIGNORE_PATH}
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712774/4934640

Comment: There is one catch about $wildcard. Make caches its results. So, if you don't find .gitignore and add it in your script, and after that test with $wildcard again, it still will report 'not found'

Comment: @AlexCohn No it doesn't! Not in 4.2.1 at any rate where `$(wildcard)` works as expected.

Comment: @bobbogo maybe you have a reference for that? I based my remark on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984461/192373.

Comment: @AlexCohn Hmmm, nothing in the git log. Works in every release since 3.82, including 3.82 AFAICT (I did try them). Fails in 3.81.